# Adding border in table header Angular Material design

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I am trying to add the border on top and bottom in the header of the table, but somehow its not showing it in angular material table.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let order"> {{order.id}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

I use the following CSS

```
th.mat-header-row {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #ffa600;
 border-top: 2px solid #ffa600;
}
```

Comment: Do you want something like this https://ibb.co/YjJXdGF?

Comment: Use `!!mportant` to overrule materials css.
`border-bottom: 2px solid #ffa600 !important;`

Comment: @Mridul Yes i want to have borders like that, can you please tell me how to do that. Thanks

Comment: @uahmed, I've added the code

Comment: @Uahmed, Did it work?

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and it worked on my MatTable

```
th.mat-header-cell {
border-bottom: 2px solid #ffa600;
border-top: 2px solid #ffa600;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below both solutions are working for me. Try these.

```
table .mat-header-row {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffa600;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffa600;
}
```

OR

```
::ng-deep .mat-header-row {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffa600;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffa600;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class `demo` to your HTML like:

```
<tr mat-header-row class="demo" *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
```

And use the following CSS:

```
.demo{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffa600;
    border-top: 2px solid #ffa600;
}
```